# iphone MGTwitterEngine - post a tweet with my app signature

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I'm using MGTwitterEngine in an iPhone app, and it works great. The one thing I want to change is the "posted from MGTwitterEngine" that appears on Twitter. Obviously I'd like it to say "from MyCoolApp", and link to the app's website.

When you register an app with Twitter (http://twitter.com/oauth_clients/create), you get this info:

```
* Consumer key
  ***a891tcxSvL6QpEeo12g
* Consumer secret
  ***MqeRIXiWsecretAdAjCgFsBN7Lef12f3uyxJFrs
* Request token URL
  http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token
* Access token URL
  http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token
* Authorize URL
  http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize
```

Where do you input this information in the current release of MGTwitterEngine?

Comment: Are you sure you want to post the keys here?

Comment: I think he censored the first three digits, but yeah, maybe it would've been best not to post them at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can find detailed information on how to do this in the Readme:
http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGTwitterEngine/README.txt

You mentioned that you already received your token, so the next step would be to call the method

```
- (void)setClientName:(NSString *)name version:(NSString *)version URL:(NSString *)url token:(NSString *)token;
```

on your MGTwitterEngine instance.

Comment: This changes the signature to 'from web' instead of MGTwitterEngine, but still doesn't set the app name to what you're passing in. (it's a name that been registered with Twitter's oAuth.) –

Answer (score 1):

From Twitters new FAQ for applications

> If you would like tweets from your application to recieve a source parameter, please register an application and implement OAuth authentication. We will automatically include your application as the source for any tweets sent from your application.
>
> We originally allowed applications to create a source paramter for non-OAuth use but that has been discontinued. Applications pre-OAuth source parameters will remain active, but new registrations are no longer accepted.

So it looks as if you're gonna have to be doing some work!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using this demo by Ben Gottlieb:

http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Do a search for REPLACE ME and you will able to find where you need to input your consumer key & secret.

The user has to grant your app permission via the Twitter website so it's a bit ugly when you run it the 1st time but it works. I don't know of any alternatives at present - hopefully Twitter will update the process soon. You only have to do the ugly OAuth authentication once. After that, this line:

```
[_engine sendUpdate: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already Updated. %@", [NSDate date]]];
```

will post an update to your twitter account that should be appended with "from MyCoolApp".

Comment: I can't make it work. I succeed with authentication, but sendUpdate doesn't update at all. Please help with some suggestion where I might be wrong. Thanks

Comment: @AlexTau I have same problem as you felt.Is it any solution for this problem??